# get newly registered customer detail

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

I want to get newly registered customer detail to send to third party.
Here is my code:

```
if($current_controller_action == 'customer_account_index'){

    Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
    $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

    if($session->isLoggedIn())
    {
        echo $session->getCustomer()->getId();
        echo $session->getCustomer()->getEmail();
    }else{
        echo "Not logged in";
    }
}
```

I tried to get only newly registered customer not the login customer on myaccount page. on this page 'customer_account_index' action working not "customer_register_success".

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any criteria that define who is "new customer"?

Comment: you can use `customer_register_success` event to get new registered customer details.

Comment: no i didn't define any criteria for this. @PYYick but i want to send the registered customer email to third party and i used above code in my "head.phtml". when i clicked on 'register' button it redirects to myaccount page and "customer_account_index" controller action is used there and when any one login it also redirect to myaccount page so head file function again run.

Comment: 'customer_register_success' is not working on myaccount page. @mansi

Comment: You can add new boolean column / attribute to customers like 'new_customer'. For every login check column and if its true, send third party and change it to false.

Comment: yw ;) let me know if you have any troubles